# Is there a word for "flashbacks within flashbacks"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any single word in English for **flashbacks within flashbacks**?

Comment: Perhaps *meta-flashback*.

Comment: If you were talking about dreams within dreams, I'd say, "Inception."

Comment: @J.R.,Not really,perhaps Inception was a good movie.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj: Yes, not really. I guess I should have added the ;^) emoticon.

Comment: seems inceptionmania to all?

Answer (score 4):

I've heard the term "nested flashback" before (as in "nested stories"). A non-authoritative example:

http://literarylab.blogspot.com/2011/08/nesting-flashbacks-or-not.html

That's not a single word, though...

Answer (score 2):

I'm joining Brett's comment. **Metaflashback**.

(Don't think there would be an hyphen.)

Comment: Is metaflashback a new word?

Comment: @Vijin: Yes, and only certain technically-minded readers would understand it.

Answer (score 2):

According to tvtropes.org, a flashback within a flashback is called an "Inception Flashback."

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlashbackWithinAFlashback

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE, Tom. Very nice first answer. Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about ELU.SE when you stick around :)

Answer (score 0):

In computer programming that would be called

Recursive flashback.

Or

Recursion of flashbacks.

Or more descriptively, having a flashback within a flashback within a flashback would be

Third level of flashback recursion.

Perhaps, in a less technical situation, the lyrics of the song "The windmills your mind" could offer some guidance.

Comment: like recursive fn?

Comment: Not quite, because in programming a recursive function is specifically a function that calls itself - so it would only be a recursive flashback if it was a flashback about itself.

Comment: A recursive dream - the dream is the function. But at every level of recursion the function or the dream need not be dreaming of the same.